# unable to close my excel whenever there is another excel open

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Whenever I try to close my macros consisting Excel file, it closes for a couple of seconds, re-opens on its own, and bugs out, giving me an object not defined error in the following code -

```
Option Explicit

Public TimerCell As Range
Public TimerValue As Range
Public StopTimer As Boolean
Public EndTime As Double

Public Sub TimeCounter()
  If Not StopTimer Then
    If EndTime - Now < 0 Then
        EndTime = Now + TimerValue 'Specifically in this line
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    TimerCell = EndTime - TimeValue(Now)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "TimeCounter" 'the clock runs every second
  End If
End Sub
```

I am using this code to run a second by second timer on the screen and refresh all my macros in 10 minutes at the completion of the timer.

It gives me an `Object variable not defined error` in the line notated above. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because `TimerValue` has not yet been set (the instances of public variables are destroyed when excel is closed).  You should either store the values in a `xlVeryHidden` sheet or just add a condition that checks if `TimerValue` is `Nothing` and handle it accordingly (depending on what you need `TimerValue` for)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have declared Timervalue as 10 minutes and end time as 0 and endtime =0 in another module from where this module is called after re-setting these values to as mentioned above.  Sub counting()

Set TimerValue = Worksheets("DS").Range("A52")
Set TimerCell = Worksheets("WALL LEVEL PPW - V2").Range("P3")
EndTime = 0
StopTimer = False
TimeCounter

End Sub

Comment: @mohitkhullar is the value in TimerValue a date?

Comment: It has a timevalue of 10 minutes

Comment: @mohitkhullar Im asking if the value is a `date` type